# sending sim 808 gps data to firebase using nodemcu... sending 0 data

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, arduino, gps, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am using a nodemcu as a means to get the data from my sim 808 module using the df robot library and sending the data gathered to my firebase real-time database. although there are no errors in the code i am sending no data however. the code below is just a modified version of the sample codes of firebasearduino and dfrobot library.

This is the code i am using:

```html
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#define FIREBASE_HOST "mcuu-xxxx.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#define WIFI_SSID "xxxxxxx"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "xxxxxxxxxx"
#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define PIN_TX    4
#define PIN_RX    5
SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_TX,PIN_RX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);//Connect RX,TX,PWR,

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  // connect to wifi.
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connected: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);

  
  while(!sim808.init()) { 
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("Sim808 init error\r\n");
  }

  //************* Turn on the GPS power************
  if( sim808.attachGPS())
      Serial.println("Open the GPS power success");
  else 
      Serial.println("Open the GPS power failure");
  

}

int n = 0;

void loop() {

Serial.print("Latgps: ");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lat, 8);
Serial.print("Longps: ");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lon, 8);

  // set value
  Firebase.setFloat("latitude",sim808.GPSdata.lat);
  // handle error
  if (Firebase.failed()) {
      Serial.print("firebase connection failed");
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());  
      return;
  }
  delay(1000);
  
  // update value
  Firebase.setFloat("longitude", sim808.GPSdata.lon);
  // handle error
  if (Firebase.failed()) {
      Serial.print("firebase connection failed");
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());  
      return;
  }
  delay(1000);

  // get value 
  Serial.print("latitudefire: ");
  Serial.println(Firebase.getFloat("latitude"));
  Serial.print("longitudefire: ");
  Serial.println(Firebase.getFloat("longitude"));
  delay(1000);

  // set string value
  Firebase.setString("message", "xxxxxxxx");
  // handle error
  if (Firebase.failed()) {
      Serial.print("setting /message failed:");
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());  
      return;
  }
  delay(1000);
 
}


SERIAL MONITOR:

connected: 192.168.1.6
Open the GPS power success
Latgps: 0.00000000
Longps: 0.00000000
latitudefire: 0.00
longitudefire: 0.00
Latgps: 0.00000000
Longps: 0.00000000
latitudefire: 0.00
longitudefire: 0.00
Latgps: 0.00000000
Longps: 0.00000000
latitudefire: 0.00
longitudefire: 0.00
```